# Django : In a view how do I obtain the sessionid which will be part of the Set-Cookie header of following response?

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-authentication

In case of views that contain login or logout,
this sessionid is different from the one submitted in request's Coockie header.
I need to retrieve it before returning response for some purpose.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Clarification : I need to retrieve it between 'login(...)' and 'return HttpResponse(...)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to access this via `request.session.session_key`

Comment: Ahh.. I mistakenly presumed that request.session fetches session_key from the request object recieved and wont change !  
Django turned out to be more intelligent than my expectations :P  
Thanks a lot !!